# Tem como abrir o outllok através do php, sem ser mailto?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de pedido que envia email automático para os representantes com anexo de um arquivo pdf feito em fpdf, mas agora a empresa solicitou que ao invés de enviar automático gostaria de usar o outlook como alternativa de envio, pois assim receberia aviso de recebimento e confirmação e manteria um histórico no outllok até que o pedido seja efetuado, falo `outlook` pois todos os usuários que utilizam o sistema tem ele instalado nas maquinas. Sei que no `C# asp.net` isto é possível, mas em `PHP` não encontrei nada relacionado ao assunto.

Ou existe uma biblioteca em php que poderia utilizar de forma semelhante ao webmail que poderia ser chamada toda vez que concluímos um pedido?

Estou utilizando este link para envio ele até preenche o email do destinatário e o assunto, mas não anexa o pdf gerado automaticamente.

```html
<a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=Envio de pedido&body=Por favor atentar aos ítens">Enviar</a>
```

Comment: Configurar o outlook como cliente de email padrão na maquina, resolveria o problema?

Comment: Ele já é o cliente padrão, o problema esta em anexar o pdf de forma dinâmica, sem fazer o download do arquivo e anexar de forma manual, no `aspx` eu utilizo uma dll que integra o outlook ao sistema e envio e-mail interno com ele, sei que dessa forma não é possível em `php` por isso criei um link para chamar o programa padrão.

Comment: `gostaria de usar o outlook como alternativa de envio, pois assim receberia aviso de recebimento` -> o ideal é descobrir como o Outlook consegue fazer isso, e replicar a funcionalidade nos emails gerados através de PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondendo o cerne da sua pergunta, infelizmente o PHP não irá conseguir fazer o que deseja, pois, como ele roda no servidor, ele não irá conseguir fazer esse intercâmbio entre o servidor e a máquina cliente da forma que está propondo.

---

**Entretanto...**

Fiz uma breve pesquisa sobre bibliotecas de webmail em PHP e encontrei algo que pode ser interessante ao seu sistema, que pode ser integrado a ele: https://afterlogic.org/webmail-lite

Segundo a documentação ele é "*livre e de código aberto*". Talvez com ele seja possível fazer uma integração ao seu sistema, chamá-lo quando finalizado o pedido e já inserir todas as informações de envio, inclusive o anexo (talvez um bom desenvolvedor seja necessário para fazer isso).

Caso consiga uma solução em PHP (como um webmail), seria interessante deixar depois um *feedback* para que possamos saber se deu certo afim de ajudar outros com a mesma demanda.

Comment: Esse webmail lite parece ser a interface de email propriamente dita, certo? O front-end para você como usuário final usar feliz e contente?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se quiser abrir um vinho tb, não faz mal. :)

Answer (score 2):

Existe como usando `exec`, mas isso exige que o PHP esteja sendo utilizado no lado do cliente, *o que não é comum*.

Segundo a documentação do [Outlook CLI](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Outlook):

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m seu@email.com
```

*Existem outros comandos/parâmetros disponíveis.*

---

Portanto, poderia utilizar:

```
exec('outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m seu@email.com');
```

Talvez seja necessário especificar o caminho, então:

```
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\outlook.exe" /c ipm.note /m seu@email.com');
```

Apenas cuidado com o e-mail inserido, porque ele pode ser um texto malicioso, no qual seria possível executar um código definido pelo atacante, afinal você está inserindo ele num `exec`. Se o email for `seu@email.com & notepad.exe` iria abrir o `notepad.exe`, por exemplo.

---

Novamente, é preciso que o cliente esteja executando o PHP, o que com certeza não é aplicável a maior parte dos casos!